# Is it ok to call closures in UIKit UIViewController from Hosted SwiftUI View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, closures

I'm hosting `ContentView` in `WrapperViewController` like this:

```
class WrapperViewController: UIViewController {
    
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        
        self.view = UIView()

        var contentView = ContentView()
        contentView.buttonTapped = { [weak self] in
            self?.tappedButton()
        }
        
        let contentViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        
        self.addChild(contentViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(contentViewController.view)

        contentViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        contentViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        contentViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    
    func tappedButton() {
        print("tapped button")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var buttonTapped: (() -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap me") {
            buttonTapped?()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling `buttonTapped` in the `WrapperViewController` from `ContentView`, but is this fine? "tapped button" is getting printed, but I read this [article](https://ohmyswift.com/blog/2020/01/10/why-should-we-avoid-using-closures-in-swift-structs/) that said

> When you use closures in structs, the closure behaves as a reference type, and the problem starts there. The closures need to have a reference to the environment outside so that the environment can be modified when the closure body is executed.
>
> ```
> struct Car {
>    var speed: Float = 0.0
>    var increaseSpeed: (() -> ())?
> }
> var myCar = Car()
> myCar.increaseSpeed = {
>     myCar.speed += 30 // The retain cycle occurs here. We cannot use [weak myCar] as myCar is a value type.
> }
> ```

So should I use a closure here? Or am I supposed to do something else?

Comment: *but is this fine?* - it is fine. The case described in that article is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We cannot use [weak myCar] as myCar is a value type.

In the example from the article, `myCar` is a *struct*.

However, in your code:

```
contentView.buttonTapped = { [weak self] in
    self?.tappedButton()
}
```

`self` is a `UIViewController` which is a *class* (and a reference type).

Your use of `[weak self]` is perfectly fine: the closure will keep a weak reference to the UIViewController and when you tap a button, the `tappedButton()` function will be called. Which is probably what you expect.